# Variance of geometric random walk

Tags: variance, mean, binomial-distribution, expected-value, random-walk

I am trying to calculate the mean and variance of the following simple random walk:

Suppose we start from 1. With probability $p$ it can increase to $a$, and with probability $q =1−p$ decrease to $b$.

The walk follows these steps, therefore in the next step it can have three outcomes:

- $a^2$ with probability $p^2$,
- $ab$ with probability $2pq$, and
- $b^2$ with probability $q^2$.

I managed to calculate the mean of step $n$: $E_n=(ap+bq)^n$. What is the variance of step $n$?

Comment: I am not following your math at all.  Why are you multiplying step sizes?

Answer (score 3):

For each $k$ between $0$ and $n$ inclusive, the chance of $k$ steps up (and therefore $n-k$ steps down) is given by the Binomial distribution as $\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}.$ By the definition of expectation as the sum of the probabilities times the values,

$$\mu_n^{(1)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k}\, a^k b^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (ap)^k (bq)^{n-k} = (ap + bq)^n.$$

The final equality is the Binomial Theorem.  This agrees with the value of $E_n$ you already found.

**The variance can be found in terms of the expectation of the *square* of the walk's values, exactly paralleling the previous calculation:**

$$\mu_n^{(2)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k}\, \left(a^k b^{n-k}\right)^\color{red}2 = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (a^\color{red}2p)^k (b^\color{red}2q)^{n-k} = (a^\color{red}2p + b^\color{red}2q)^n.$$

Therefore

$$\text{Variance} = \mu_n^{(2)} - \mu_n^{(1)} = (a^2p + b^2q)^n - (ap + bq)^{2n}.$$